# How to check if a file is uploaded to S3 bucket in last X days using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm a node js developer and new yo AWS. I'm working on a task related where I need to check whether a file being uploaded to S3 bucket in last 90 days or not.

Usually when a file is uploaded to S3, Lambda will be triggered and it's data being stored into Cache.

But if not uploaded, I need to trigger a Lambda function and load that file's data to Cache.

Is there any way to check if a file is uploaded to S3 bucket using Node.JS so that I could trigger the Lambda.

Does Cron Job useful to check for the file upload or is there any better approach to do this.

Comment: Try to do a get for the file and if it exists, check the creation date? If creation <= X days, then it's a yes otherwise its a no? Does that sound reasonable to you

Comment: Yes @ErmiyaEskandary that's what am gonna do. But the confusion here is, is it possible to check if the file is available in s3 and get its uploaded timestamp.

Comment: Yes, use the HEAD request (HeadObject) to see if the object exists without pulling it fully down which will also return the `Last-Modified` field giving you the uploaded timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary will definitely try that

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you should try using the SNS. Use an SNS topic as a destination for AWS S3 Event notification (New object created events), then use the topic to trigger your lambda. The topic payload will give you relevant information such as timestamp. This way you are sure that "when a file is not uploaded" then your lambda is not triggered and you can run a custom logic to upload the file to Cache ad-hoc. 
You cannot elegantly accomplish this using CRON job per say, also using CRON will also trigger your lambda un-neccesary incurring you costs (due to a set frequency).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for this suggestion. I'm new to AWS and confused on these. Will definitely look into these.